# Как в Unity программно создать AudioClip вытащив файл для него из project?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я знаю что можно этот файл перетащить из редактора в AudioClip вручную, но у меня 70 зон и это тяжело. Пробовал так не работает:

```
public  AudioClip Music
void Start(){

        Music = AudioClip.Create("Audio/Goat.mp3", samplerate * 2, 1, samplerate, true);
        if (Music != null) {
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().clip = Music;
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот получилось так: я создал папку Resources и перенес туда аудиофайлы в коде использовал это:

```
Music = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Goat");
```